# Scapy BPF filter for TLS client hello and TCP SYN

Tags: scapy, bpf, sniffer

I'm trying to write a BPF filter for scapy's `sniff()` to capture packets that are TLSClientHello packets OR TCP SYN packets. Here's what I have:

```
sniff(filter="tcp dst port 443 and ((tcp[((tcp[12] & 0xf0) >> 2)] = 0x16) or (tcp[13] & 0x02 = 1))", prn=process_packet, iface=iface, store=False)
```

The sniff is only picking up on TLSClientHello though. For some reason, SYN packets aren't getting through. What is wrong with the BPF?

Comment: Take a look at here: https://gist.github.com/LeeBrotherston/92cc2637f33468485b8f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logical `and` for the filter portion supposed to catch the TCP SYN will return 2, not 1. So this:

```
(tcp[13] & 0x02 = 1)
```

Should be:

```
(tcp[13] & 0x02 = 2)
```

Or alternatively (at least with tcpdump, I haven't tried with Scapy):

```
(tcp[tcpflags] & tcp-syn != 0)
```

Comment: @helloCode0135 Did you test it? It still doesn't show SYN packets for me when combined with the first part of your filter :-/